# How do I create a text where it will show current date, but once date is selected it will show the selected date instead? Using SwiftUI. Thank you

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I'm a new learner to programming and SwiftUI and I am trying to learn how create a personal diary app.

I want a text to show the current date on startup, but when you select a different date on the calendar, it'll show the selected date instead. I tried to use an if else condition but it doesn't work properly. I think it's because I used "if singleisPresented != false" so it only appears when I click the button. But what I should use instead? Many thanks guys.

I am using the RKCalendar (https://github.com/RaffiKian/RKCalendar) to help me with the calendar.

```
                Button(action: { self.singleIsPresented.toggle() }) {
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .frame(width: 18, height: 25)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$singleIsPresented, content: {
                RKViewController(isPresented: self.$singleIsPresented, rkManager: self.rkManager)})
                .onAppear(perform: startUp)
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())

                if singleIsPresented != false {
                Text(self.getTextFromDate(date: self.rkManager.selectedDate))
                    .font(.headline)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)

            } else {
                Text(currentDate(date: Date()))
                    .font(.headline)
                .fontWeight(.bold)

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Button(action: { self.singleIsPresented.toggle() }) {
                Text("Example 1 - Single Date Selection").foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$singleIsPresented, content: {
                RKViewController(isPresented: self.$singleIsPresented, rkManager: self.rkManager1)})

            if rkManager1.selectedDate != nil {
            Text(self.getTextFromDate(date: self.rkManager1.selectedDate))
            } else {
                Text("\(Date())")
            }
```

This checks if the user selected a date and will show the current date until the user selects one. This way, even if they look at the calendar and don't select a date, it'll still show the current date.